# Will the entire process block when a system call is made or only the thread?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, kernel, cpu

If a thread made a system call, will the entire process block until the kernel finishes executing the system call, or will only the thread that made the system call be blocked?

Comment: In linux threads are separate processes all-together. So in a sense, yes the entire process (read thread) does block until the system call is complete. If you are thinking strictly programatically, then no other threads won't block because one has made a system call

Comment: Would kind of defeat the purpose of threading if one thread could constantly block all other threads with an unrelated operation.

Comment: @kaylum I have a related question if you don't mind, why would the thread that made the system call be blocked? is it because when a system call is made, the CPU switches to kernel mode, and so if the thread was not blocked, then the thread can execute privileged instructions (for example: `hlt`)?

Comment: Well, think of a "normal" function call. Does the caller get to continue before the function exits? No (in general) because the point of calling a function is so that it will do something for you and then you can continue executing. Same with a syscall - it is a request for the kernel to do something and it does not make sense to continue until that is done. Note that "do something" could be to start off a longer operation and it does not mean that  that long operation has to complete before the syscall returns. I think this last point is perhaps what you are confused with.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using real threads created by the operating system, the answer is NO. The threads execute independently and are scheduled independently.

If you are using threads simulated by a library (which you can do in Linux if you are really crazy), then all the threads might block, depending upon the system call at issue.